# Difference between GLSL shader variable types?

Tags: opengl

When seeing some OpenGL examples, some use the following types of variables when declaring them at the top of the shader:

`in`
`out`

and some use:

`attribute`
`varying`
`uniform`

What is the difference? Are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: Already answered [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/in-out-keywords-in-glsl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`attribute` and `varying` were removed from GLSL 1.40 and above (desktop GL version 3.1) in core OpenGL. OpenGL ES 2 still uses them, but were removed from ES 3.0 code.

You can still use the old constructs in compatibility profiles, but `attribute` only maps to vertex shader `in`puts. `varying` maps to both VS `out`puts and FS `in`puts.

`uniform` has not changed; it still means what it always has: values set by the outside world which are fixed during a rendering operation.

Answer (score 4):

In modern OpenGL, you have a series of shaders hooked up to a pipeline.  A simple pipeline will have a vertex shader and a fragment shader.

For each shader in the pipeline, the `in` is the input to that stage, and the `out` is the output to that stage.  The `out` from one stage will get matched with the `in` from the next stage.

A `uniform` can be used in any shader and will stay constant for the entire draw call.

If you want an analogy, think of it as a factory.  The `in` and `out` are conveyor belts going in and out of machines.  The `uniform` are knobs that you turn on a machine to change how it works.

### Example

Vertex shader:

```
// Input from the vertex array
in vec3 VertPos;
in vec2 VertUV;

// Output to fragment shader
out vec2 TexCoord;

// Transformation matrix
uniform mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
```

Fragment shader:

```
// Input from vertex shader
in vec2 TexCoord;

// Output pixel data
out vec4 Color;

// Texture to use
uniform sampler2D Texture;
```

### Older OpenGL

In older versions of OpenGL (2.1 / GLSL 1.20), other keywords were used instead of `in` and `out`:

- `attribute` was used for the inputs to the vertex shader.
- `varying` was used for the vertex shader outputs and fragment shader inputs.
- Fragment shader outputs were implicitly declared, you would use `gl_FragColor` instead of specifying your own.

Comment: And what about the "pass" variables? Those are also missing from the old stackoverflow page, which Tulon linked. Only the vertex shader can pass them to the pixel shader, or vica versa too?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass"?  The `out` variable from a vertex shader matches the `in` variable from a fragment shader, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: ah sorry, now I double checked the source, and those were normal in/out parameters, just the names had a "pass_" prefix.